# Issue with Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I am a UI developer and I am completely new to Angular, however, I understand jQuery. I have joined a new company and they use Angular JS with JAVA. I have been assigned a task over which I am banging head for the past few days. I've come under the scanner now.

Basically I have a table in .html page to which data is coming (Sorry, I am told that I would need atleast 10 reputation to post a screen shot). Now I want to other column in that table.

I have tried adding that column in columns_panel.js but still it is not coming in the grid by default.

I understand that my question is not clear over here, but trust me, even my Team lead is also not willing to disclose any thing.

Can any JS guru's be help to me?

```
<div columns-panel columns="columns" show-panel="showColumnsPanel"></div>

<table class="responsive">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
            </th>
            <th class="isFlagged">
                <div class="flag"></div>
            </th>

            <th ng-repeat="column in columns" ng-click="sortBy(column)" class="{{ column }}">
                <a class="th-inner">
                    {{ column | translate }}
                    <span ng-show="isSortColumn(column)"
                          ng-class="{'sort-icon-desc': !isSortAscending(),
                            'sort-icon-asc': isSortAscending()}">
                    </span>
                </a>
            </th>
            <!--<th class="toggle-columns-header">-->
            <!--<a class="th-inner" ng-click="showColumnsPanel = !showColumnsPanel">+</a>-->
            <!--</th>-->
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="dispute in disputes.currentPage"
            ng-class="isSelected(dispute) ? '{{ dispute | disputeTrClass }} checked-dispute' : '{{ dispute | disputeTrClass }}'"
            ng-click="goToDisputeDetails(dispute)">
            <td ng-class="isNegative(dispute) ? 'select-dispute alert-corner' : 'select-dispute'" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()">
                <input id="select-dispute-{{ dispute.id }}" type="checkbox" ng-click="toggleSelectedDispute(dispute)" ng-checked="isSelected(dispute)" ng-disabled="!dispute.isFlaggable" ng-hide="!dispute.isFlaggable" />
                <label for="select-dispute-{{ dispute.id }}" ng-hide="!dispute.isFlaggable"></label>
            </td>

            <td class="isFlagged" ng-click="toggleFlag(dispute, $event)">
                <div ng-show="dispute.isFlaggable" class="flag {{ dispute.isFlagged ? 'flagged' : 'unflagged' }}"></div>
            </td>

            <td ng-repeat="column in columns" class="{{ column }}">
                <div data-ng-switch data-on="column">
                    <div data-ng-switch-when="reason">
                        {{  dispute[column] }}
                        <span class="reason-code" ng-if="dispute.reason !== 'N/A'">{{ dispute.reasonCode }}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div data-ng-switch-when="status">
                        {{ dispute[column]=="Urgent Response Required"?"Response Required":dispute[column] }}
                    </div>




                    <div data-ng-switch-when="amount">

                        <div ng-if="isNegative(dispute)" class="negative">
                            -<span class="currency">$</span>{{ dispute[column] * -1 | number:2 }}
                        </div>
                        <div ng-if="isPositive(dispute)">
                            <span class="currency">$</span>{{ dispute[column] | number:2 }}
                        </div>
                    </div>





                    <div data-ng-switch-when="dateReceived">
                        {{ dispute[column] | translatedDate }}
                    </div>
                    <div data-ng-switch-when="respondBy">
                        {{ dispute[column] | translatedDate }}
                    </div>
                    <div data-ng-switch-when="respondedOn">
                        {{ dispute[column] | translatedDate }}
                    </div>
                    <div data-ng-switch-default>
                        {{ dispute[column] }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>

            <!--<td class="{{ columns[columns.length - 1] }}"></td>-->
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<!-- No Disputes To Display -->
<div disputes-table-empty></div>

<!-- Error Message -->
<div disputes-table-error></div>
<style type="text/css">
    .status {
        padding-left: 27px !important;
    }
</style>
```

This is the Model

```
    DisputeModule.value('Dispute', function (attributes) {
      this.id = attributes.id;
      this.amount = attributes.amount;
      this.cancelDate = attributes.cancelDate;
      this.cancellationNumber = attributes.cancellationNumber;
      this.cancelZone = attributes.cancelZone;
      this.cardDeposit = attributes.cardDeposit;
      this.cardMemberName = attributes.cardMemberName;
      this.cardNumber = attributes.cardNumber;
      this.chargeAmount = attributes.chargeAmount;
      this.chargeDate = attributes.chargeDate;
      this.creditReceived = attributes.creditReceived;
      this.dateReceived = attributes.dateReceived;
      this.disputeNumber = attributes.disputeNumber;
      this.description = attributes.description;
      this.isFlaggable = attributes.isFlaggable;
      this.isFlagged = attributes.isFlagged;
      this.locationID = attributes.locationID;
      this.merchandiseReturned = attributes.merchandiseReturned;
      this.merchandiseType = attributes.merchandiseType;
      this.merchantAccount = attributes.merchantAccount;
      this.modeOfReturn = attributes.modeOfReturn;
      this.originalCardNbr = attributes.originalCardNbr;
      this.payeeLocationId = attributes.payeeLocationId;
      this.payeeSENbr = attributes.payeeSENbr;
      this.reason = attributes.reason;
      this.reasonCode = attributes.reasonCode;
      this.referenceNumber = attributes.referenceNumber;
      this.reservationCanceled = attributes.reservationCanceled;
      this.reservationCanceledDate = attributes.reservationCanceledDate;
      this.stage = attributes.stage;
      this.status = attributes.status;
    });

This is the columns_panel.js

DisputeModule.directive('columnsPanel', function (BASE_URL) {
  var defaultColumns = [
    'disputeNumber',
    'status',
    'dateReceived',
    'respondBy',
    'respondedOn',
    'type',
    'reason',
    'cardNumber',
    'originalCardNbr',
    'transactionDate',
    'referenceNumber',
    'resolution',
    'merchantAccount',
    'locationID',
    'payeeSENbr',
    'payeeLocationId',
    'chargeAmount',
    'amount'
  ];

  var availableColumns = [
    'disputeNumber',
    'status',
    'dateReceived',
    'respondBy',
    'respondedOn',
    'type',
    'reason',
    'cardNumber',
    'originalCardNbr',
    'transactionDate',
    'referenceNumber',
    'resolution',
    'merchantAccount',
    'locationID',
    'payeeSENbr',
    'payeeLocationId',
    'chargeAmount',
    'amount'
  ];
  var columns = defaultColumns.slice();

  return {
    templateUrl: BASE_URL + '/resources/views/columns_panel.html',
    scope: {
      columns: '=',
      showPanel: '='
    },
    controller: function ($scope) {
      function addColumn(column) {
        var tmpColumns = $scope.columns.slice();
        tmpColumns.push(column);
        tmpColumns.sort(function (a, b) {
          return $scope.availableColumns.indexOf(a) - $scope.availableColumns.indexOf(b);
        });
        updateColumns(tmpColumns);
      }

      $scope.columns = columns;
      $scope.availableColumns = availableColumns;

      $scope.isSelected = function (column) {
        return $scope.columns.indexOf(column) > -1;
      };

      $scope.toggleColumn = function (column) {
        var columnIndex = $scope.columns.indexOf(column);
        if (columnIndex === -1) {
          addColumn(column);
        } else {
          $scope.columns.splice(columnIndex, 1);
        }
      };

      $scope.reset = function () {
        updateColumns(defaultColumns.slice());
      };

      $scope.close = function () {
        $scope.showPanel = false;
      };

      function updateColumns(newColumns) {
        $scope.columns = columns = newColumns;
      }
    }
  };
});
```

I want to add **"chargeAmount"** to appear in the grid/table

Comment: can you check what you have in columns ? i think your cols are referenced inside, if i'm right you maybe have to push chargeAmount in it

Comment: How do I push that Thomas?
Little bit of code would really help

Comment: try to find columns in your JS and show me the code

Comment: It' there in the question. after the model you can find columns_panel.js

Comment: ok my bad, i didn't there was a scroll

Answer (score 0):

1. you must have another columns somewhere, this columns

   `<div columns-panel columns="columns" show-panel="showColumnsPanel"></div>`

try to add to your directive datas (the columns).

1. they are called here

   `scope: {
     columns: '=',
     showPanel: '='
   },`
2. and gave to the directive scope here

   $scope.columns = columns;

so in your controller try to see what you have in columns

Comment: Thanks Thomas, let me try my luck

Comment: It didn't Thomas.. I am still not able to add that column to my table